# xml Image filepath from variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm struggling to find a way to get a line in a resulting XML-file to contain a image file path.

The resulting line should look like this in the final XML:

`<img href="file:///Volumes/disk/image_folder/image.psd" />`

Where image.psd come from this input XML:

```
<row>
    <col4>image.psd</col4>
</row>
```

Comment: The path-to-file is constant and pointing to _image_folder always? Please share part of your XSLT that does the col4 -> img transformation. It should be straight forward to prefix the path in there.

Comment: Just edit your post instead of putting stuff into comments...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the path to the images are constant, and the incoming XML has the filename in the tag

The XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/csv">
<xsl:for-each select="row">
    <xsl:variable name="filename"><xsl:value-of select="col1"/>.dita </xsl:variable>
<xsl:result-document href="{col1}.xml" method="xml">
        <bilkort>
            <artnummer>Art nr: <xsl:value-of select="col1"/></artnummer>
            <rubrik><xsl:value-of select="col2"/></rubrik>
            <innehåll><xsl:value-of select="col3"/></innehåll>
            <img href="file:///Volumes/disk/image_folder/image.psd" />
        </bilkort>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Incoming XML looks like this:

```
<csv>
<row>
  <col1>Partno</col1>
  <col2>Headline</col2>
  <col3>Content</col3>
  <col4>imagefilename</col4>
</row>
</csv>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
<xsl:variable name="imagepath" select="'Volumes/disk/image_folder'" />
<xsl:variable name="imagefile"><xsl:value-of select="col4"/></xsl:variable>
<img href="file:///{$imagepath}/{$imagefile}"/>
```

This works for me